# How to hijack the promise resolution after a generic find on an ember-data model?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, promise

I need to inspect the ember-data model coming back from a basic find manually (this model is not bound to the template and instead I need to apply some logic dynamically)

So far I've tried the following (with no luck)

```
App.Foo.find().then(function(model) {
  console.log("here with the ember-data payload");
  console.log(model.get('length'));
}, function(error) {
  console.log("broken");
});
```

The success block does fire but it always seems to return 0 results, yet when I view the network tab in chrome it shows a valid json payload that works outside of this promise hook I'm using.

is it possible to hijack the promise resolution with ember-data rev 11 ?

Answer (score 5):

The `App.Foo.find()` returns list of models, namely, a `DS.AdapterPopulatedRecordArray`, which is *not* array, and thus doesn't have the *length* property. But it has a *content* property, which is array of models.
So in your example, you should use `console.log(model.content.length);` to make it work:

```
App.Foo.find().then(function(result) {
  console.log("here with the ember-data payload");
  console.log(result.content.length);
  console.log(result.objectAt(0));
}, function(error) {
  console.log("broken");
});
```

Note that you cannot use the `[]` operator on `DS.AdapterPopulatedRecordArray`, because it is not array. See [Ember guide on DS](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/). You should use the `objectAt` instead: `result.objectAt(0);`.

Comment: This always returns 0 for some odd reason (even when I see a valid json payload come across the wire)

Comment: `array.get('length')` **will** give you the length

Answer (score 2):

`App.Model.find().then(function(notes) {console.log(notes.content.length)})`
returned 5 for me which is the correct return value for my app.

I think your syntax is correct though perhaps you have issues with the data being returned by your server?  Maybe it's not serializing into actual records for whatever reason.  Might be worth double-checking.

Comment: What version of ember and ember-data are you using?

Comment: latest build from master for Ember and rev11 for data